# How do I delete particular NSString from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

Help me to sort-out my problem, I've been stuck over here.

I've also seen many questions similar to this, with same problem. But none-of them solved my problem. That's why I need to ask similar question on Stack.

I've NSMutableArray i.e `NSMutableArray *arrNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ABC", @"DEF", @"GHI", nil];`

Now I want to delete `GHI` from this array. So I've tried this way, but it doesn't 
 work-out. Please help me.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSMutableArray *arrDeletedGTINS = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        arrDeletedGTINS = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"deletedArr"];


NSLog(@"%@", arrDeletedGTINS); will give this output ->
```

(
        00000000000017
    )

```
    if ([arrDeletedGTINS containsObject:@"00000000000017"]) {
        [arrDeletedGTINS removeObject:@"00000000000017"];
    }

    [userDefaults setObject:arrDeletedGTINS forKey:@"deletedArr"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
```

If I'm going some-where wrong then please correct me. I'm learning iOS.
Please help me.

Comment: You are accessing the index from a different array. Replace the crashing line with `[arrNames removeObjectAtIndex:index];`.

Comment: Please correct me, I've no Idea about this.

Comment: [arrNames removeObjectAtIndex:index]; you fine index from "arrNames" array and removeobject from this array "arrDeletedGTINS" so..

Comment: So Sorry it's typing mistake.

Comment: what about `removeObject` for e.g `[arrNames removeObject: str];`

Comment: It never crashed at my end. There is something else going on.

Comment: Copy paste the code from your project. **Note** - Copy paste your code. Don't write it here in the editor.

Comment: @ios try my answer

Comment: @ios : Where is your earlier code ?

Comment: From Apple's documentation…  `synchronize()` _"… this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."_ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is your issue :

```
arrDeletedGTINS = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"deletedArr"];
```

**NSUserDefault saves array as NSArray, not as NSMutableArray.**
So replace the above line by :

```
arrDeletedGTINS = [[userDefaults objectForKey:@"deletedArr"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: hey nitish what is the difference between them ? please tell me.because i dont know.

Comment: arrDeletedGTINS = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"deletedArr"]; will return NSArray, whereas arrDeletedGTINS = [[userDefaults objectForKey:@"deletedArr"] mutableCopy]; will return NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You can use **containsObject** method in an **NSMutableArray**

```
if ([arrNames containsObject:@"GHI"]) {
    [arrNames removeObject:@"GHI"];
}
```

Comment: I won't call this an alternate rather than a solution.

Comment: I know it's working fine. As a matter of fact, there will be more ways to make that fine. But it is **important** to see the real issue here, which is, removeObjectAtIndex is not working.

Comment: @Nitish i think this is not issue "removeObjectAtIndex" . see my comment its array name issue.

Comment: Yes, to which OP has replied - So Sorry it's typing mistake.

Comment: No not at-all its my typing mistake...I've tried proper array name though it is crashing.

Comment: @ios : Update your question with the complete code. I just tried the code you have shared in the question. It works perfectly fine. There is something else.

Comment: This answer is also not working. It is crashing on similar point as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Nitish yes but i give him another option this way is more efficient and reduce code.that's why i posted this answer.